# Mine field - probability

Tags: probability

We have an $x$×$y$ grid with $z$ tiles containing a mine distributed randomly. We uncover tiles randomly (each tile once) until we uncover all $z$ mines. How many tiles would it take on average to uncover all tiles with mines?

Comment: Have you tried anything on your own yet? What work have you done on this?

Comment: Does "randomly" mean that you can uncover the same tile twice?

Comment: No, after we uncover a tile, it stays uncovered. I'm sorry I didn't do any work here, because I have no idea how to do this. This is a problem from real life and last time I had combinatorics was in high school 10 years ago.

Comment: What do you mean by randomly? Random has a specific meaning in probability.

Comment: Each tile has equal chance of containing a mine. Maybe the word is redundant...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sketch:

Let $n = xy$. I assume the mines' locations as well as the choice of tiles to uncover are chosen without replacement (i.e. you cannot place a mine on a tile that already has a mine, and you cannot uncover a tile that you have already uncovered).

Instead of placing mines randomly on tiles, we can equivalently think of the setup as randomly positioning $n-z$ empty tiles and $z$ "mine tiles" on the ground. It will be useful later to give labels to the empty tiles; I will number them from $1$ to $n-z$.

Let $X$ be the number of uncoverings needed to see all mines. We can write $X$ as $$X = z + \text{number of empty tiles uncovered before the $z$th mine is uncovered}.$$
If we label the empty tiles from $1$ to $n-z$, we can write this as
$$X = z + \sum_{i=1}^{n-z} I_i$$
where
$$I_i := \begin{cases}1 & \text{if empty tile $i$ is uncovered before the $z$th mine is uncovered} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
is an indicator random variable.

You can show
$$E[I_i] = P(\text{empty tile $i$ is uncovered before the $z$th mine is uncovered}) = \frac{z}{z+1}.$$
[You should try to figure out why this is true.]

Thus
$$E[X] = z + \sum_{i=1}^{n-z} E[I_i] = z + (n-z) \frac{z}{z+1}.$$

---

Not necessary, but I prefer to think of the problem in the following equivalent formulation: you have a deck of $n$ cards, $z$ of which have a mine on them while all other cards are blank. You shuffle the deck. Revealing cards one by one from the top of the deck is like uncovering the tiles in the original problem. The question is now the following: on average, what is the position of the bottom-most mine card? (By "position" I mean the top-most card has position $1$, and the bottom-most card has position $n$.)

Comment: Under the deck formulation, it is easy to find the answer. There are $z$ cards which are mines, which divide the deck into $z+1$ sections. The cards you do _not_ inspect are those in the bottommost section. Since each of the $n-z$ blank cards is equally likely to fall in each section, the expected number of cards in the bottom section is $\frac{n-z}{z+1}$, so the expected number of cards drawn is $n-\frac{n-z}{z+1}$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Thanks for this perspective, I hadn't thought about counting from the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to approach one aspect of this because I actually wrote code for something like this around a week ago on how to generate a matrix like [this.](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fill-a-Boolean-matrix-knowing-how-many-1-are-there-for-each-row-and-for-each-column/answer/Ryan-Howe-1) The question was how to fill a boolean matrix knowing how many 1's and 0's there are in each row and columns. This was my approach.

Suppose that we have n independent Bernoulli trials with probability p which will be given by a random binomial variable $X$ denoted $X \sim Bin(n,p)$ with the mass function.
$$f(k;n,p) = \binom{n}{p} p^{k} (1-p)^{n-k} $$
the expectation of $X$ is

$$ E(X) = np$$

Then this tells on average how many 1's we expect to see in the vector.. So a collection of random binomial variables given as vectors. This gives us an $ x \times y $ grid. Let $ X_{1}, X_{2}, \cdots , X_{y} \sim Bin(x,p_{i}$) will give us a matrix $N $

Now suppose that average time to uncover a mine given by some $ Z_{1} \sim N(\mu_{1}, \sigma_{1}^{2})$ and the time to uncover a space without a mine is $Z_{2}  \sim N(\mu_{2}, \sigma_{2}^{2})$

Let the time for one column be given by

$$Y_{i} = X_{i}Z_{1} + (n-X_{i})Z_{2}  $$
$$E(Y_{i}) = np_{i}\mu_{1} + (n-np_{i})\mu_{2} $$
Then the total time is
$$\sum_{i=1}^{y} E(Y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{y} np_{i}\mu_{1} + (n-np_{i})\mu_{2} $$

supposing they are equally likely $p_{i} = \frac{1}{2} $

$$\sum_{i=1}^{y} E(Y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{y} n\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1} + (n-n\frac{1}{2})\mu_{2} $$

Considering the number of tiles is $x$ fixing this...

$$\sum_{i=1}^{y} E(Y_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{y} x\frac{1}{2}\mu_{1} + (x-x\frac{1}{2})\mu_{2} $$

Answer (score 0):

- There are $xy$ tiles
- $z$ tiles have mines
- $xy-z$ do not have mines
- Each tile without a mine has probability $\dfrac1{z+1}$ of being untouched when the last mine is found
- So the expected number of tiles untouched when the last mine is found is$\dfrac{xy-z}{z+1}$
- And the expected number of tiles inspected when the last mine is found is $xy - \dfrac{xy-z}{z+1} = (xy+1)\dfrac{z}{z+1}$